# Flex: facebook apis for flex project

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, facebook

I am very new to flex and as3. I need to Integrate facebook for flex mobile project. I integrated facebook api for android. I am searching in internet for good tutorials for integrating facebook in flex. Please suggest me good tutorials

Comment: Voting to close as the user didn't do [any research](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/) and the question is too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an all-actionscript approach to using the facebook apis that involves the facebook [flash graph api](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/) , but it is a bit buggy. As long as you are in a browser it will work for most things.

The graph api is used to prompt a user to login to their account and grant an application permission to perform things, and then to perform the desired actions to that users account. You start the whole process with the Facebook.init method:

```
Facebook.init(APP_ID, onInit);
```

Where APP_ID is your application id that you get once you create the app on facebook, and onInit is a callback function that you create, which should look like the following:

```
function onInit(result:Object, fail:Object):void{
    var opts:Object = {perms:"publish_stream"};
    if (result)  //already logged in because of existing session
        doStuff(); //in this case, publish on user's wall
    else
        Facebook.login(onLogin, opts);
}
```

The two parameters must be there. If request is defined, that means that the user has logged in. If not, prompt the user to log in, and to grant permissions to the app. Find more about permissions on the developers facebook site.

Facebook.login's first parameter is the callback function, and the second is the permissions you want the user to agree to. onLogin() is as follows:

```
function onLogin(result:Object, fail:Object):void {
            if (result) //successfully logged in
                doStuff();
            else        
                     oh_well(); // they don't want to use it.
}
```

This could will prompt the user to log in, however, it will return immediately with a null value in result. This has to do with the facebook login function being poorly scripted, if you set up your flash on a web site and debug it with the a javascript console you can see apparently it's running on a timer to see if you've exited out or not, and it never finishes. But if that's not a big deal...

...now, for doStuff. In my case I wanted to post a message, swf, and thumbnail to a user's wall. I did this with the following code:

```
function doStuff(){
    var obj:Object={
    "message": "This is a test message",
    "picture": "thumbnail.jpg",
    "source": "flash file"
     }

    Facebook.api("/me/feed", onCallApi, JSON.decode(obj), "POST"); 

}
```

Facebook.api() is really what is important. onCallApi is the callback function, JSON.decode(obj) is the json object above with the appropriate additions. "me/feed" is how Facebook connects a feed, user, friend, etc. [Learn more about that stuff here.](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) The facebook documentation has a much better method to place the flash file, using the same function but different parameters in the encoded json, but I haven't been able to get it to work (i think it's because of nested jsons). And as you can see you'll need the JSON decoder from as3corelib.

onCallAPI:

```
function onCallApi(result:Object, fail:Object):void {
    if (result) {
        //successful post
    } else {
           //unsuccessful post
    }
}
```

And that should do it for most apps.

the facebook flash api is just interfacing with the javascript api,so you'll need to import the appropriate javascript functions from facebook on the html page that embeds the flash.

You can fix facebook.login if you want, very easily. You can either keep calling Facebook.init() until a certain amount of time has passed, or generate the login window in javascript, listen for when the window is closed, and then interface with a flash callback using ExternalInterfaces to recognize the results

Answer (score 0):

In all of my attempts to work with the fcebook API for flash I encountered nonstop problems.

Facebook was voted by developers as having the world's worst API because of the constant changes and bug ridden, undocumented code. The flash libraries are going to be out of sync with what is already a horrible, broken developer experience...even though they may have worked at one time. Facebook is notorious for breaking things with no notice.

To date,my best success has come from integrating with their PHP API's to get the data I need in and out using JSON. Facebook seems to take their ( they arent responsible for flash) PHP API more seriously and it has more a hope of being up to date and working.